# How to add custom quantile lines to a scatter plot?

Tags: r

there! I am new to R, and I am currently studying thorough an online course.

In this exercises, I am plotting a scatter plot of "age" against "friend_count" using a mock social network data set "pf" using ggplot2. I was able to plot the scatter graph and the mean line without a problem using the following code:

```
ggplot(aes(x = age, y = friend_count), data = pf) +
  geom_point(color = "orange") +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean)
```

Now I am trying to plot the 10% quantile line as well. The course suggests the following code:

```
+ geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, probs = 0.1)
```

However, perhaps because I am using a newer version this does not work, and I get the error "unknown parameter: probs"
Having researched the quantile() function, I have tried the following:

```
+ geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile(y, probs = 0.1))
```

and

```
+ geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile(friend_count, probs = 0.1))
```

which say "object y not found" and "object friend_count not found" respectively. Same happened when I tried pf$friend_count.

```
+ geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile)
```

does not work either. I have even tried defining a function "quantile", but wasn't really able to.

I am sure there is an easy way to do this... Can you help?

Comment: what are you trying to do with quantile? add CI to your line?

Comment: Not sure what data set you are using. But, this code works on the mtcars data set just fine: ggplot(aes(y = mpg, x = cyl), data = mtcars) + geom_point(color = "orange") + geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, probs = 0.1). Make sure the type of 'friend_count' is numeric.

Comment: @MLavoie, yeah, in a way. The point is to add quantiles to understand the spread of the data better.

Comment: @user3949008, I copied your code exactly, and I still get "Error: Unknown parameters: probs". I am using RStudio Version 0.99.489 and R Version 3.2.3, could this be because we are using different versions?

Comment: You probably have an older version of ggplot2. Try upgrading it.

Answer (score 3):

After checking R help for stat_summary, this code finally worked for me on the Udacity example (RStudio 1.1.423):

```
ggplot(aes(x=age, y=friend_count),data=pf)+
  geom_jitter(alpha=1/20,position=position_jitter(h=0),color='orange')+
  xlim(13,90)+
  coord_trans(y="sqrt")+
  geom_line(stat='summary',fun.y=quantile,fun.args = list(0.1),
            linetype=2,color='blue')+
  geom_line(stat='summary',fun.y=quantile,fun.args = list(0.5),
            linetype=2)+
  geom_line(stat='summary',fun.y=quantile,fun.args = list(0.9),
            linetype=2,color='blue')+
  geom_line(stat='summary',fun.y = mean,
            color='green')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(pf,aes(x=age,y=friend_count)) +
geom_point(alpha=1/20,position=position_jitter(h=0), color='yellow') +
xlim(13,90) +
coord_trans(y='sqrt') +
geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y=mean)+
geom_line(stat='summary', fun.y=quantile(pf$friend_count,probs=seq(0,1,0.1)))
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.